# Local mysql settings in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I want add in my ZF2 application at begining of every mysql connection this mysql query/setting

```
SET time_zone = \'+00:00\';
```

for some reasons i couldn't do it on mysql conifiguration file.

So where i can do it?

(now i create dbadapter by config file:

```
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
      etc...
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your config file (for example in `config/autoload/global.php`)

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET time_zone = \'+00:00\''
        )
)
```